# why I could not refer ext properties in subproject

Tags: gradle

when I import spring cloud `mavenBom`,if I use code:

```
    subprojects {

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    ext {
        springCloudVersion = "Hoxton.SR8"
    }

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public/' }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencyManagement{

        dependencies {
            dependency(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.3.7.RELEASE'){
                exclude group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.16'
            }
            dependency(group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17')
            dependency('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2')
        }
        imports {
            mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}'
        }


    }

}
```

it doesn't work, and the error is :

> Could not find org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}.

if I transform `${springCloudVersion}` to `Hoxton.SR8`,it work absolutely.
so, what result in this case?

Answer (score 2):

If you want `${springCloudVersion}` to be interpreted, you need a `GString` (use double quote `"`)

https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_double_quoted_string

```
mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
```